# recordViewForm not displaying when attribute set in helper

Tags: lightning-recordviewform

When trying to display a record's field via lightning:recordViewForm, I am successful when I set the recordId attribute (ProjId) directly by defining a default value.  However, when I assign ProjId in a helper class, it doesn't display.  I am verifying that I am successfully setting ProjId in the helper class because I display it above the recordViewForm.  I don't understand why recordViewForm isn't working when ProjId is set in the helper class and it is working when I hardcode the record id when I define the ProjId attribute.

/* when I set the recordId as the default value, the recordViewForm works. */

```
<aura:attribute name="ProjId" type="String" default="" access="global" />

                    {!v.ProjId}
                   <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.ProjId}"
                          objectApiName="Project2__c">
                          <lightning:outputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="Abstract__c" />
                   </lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Here is what I am doing in the helper when the recordViewForm doesn't work.
component.set('v.ProjId','a003u00000bEWNRAA4');

Comment: Duiplicate of [<lightning:recordViewForm will not display](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222552/lightningrecordviewform-will-not-display)

Answer (score 1):

Just found my answer in another Stack Exchange question.  The solution was to put an aura if clause around the recordViewForm code and it worked.

The solution I found was at...
[<lightning:recordViewForm will not display](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222552/lightningrecordviewform-will-not-display)